# Fix Composer.json File? - Can't update anything

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, plugin

I"m trying to update mageplaza smtp plugin via composer and running into issues with composer.

I'm running the commands per their instructions on github. 
I have had magento updated to 2.3.3 community recently(supposedly), but the composer.json file still says 2.2.12. Is there a way to rebuild composer.json?

I'm getting these errors:

```
> user@user.user.com [www]# composer require mageplaza/module-smtp
> Using version ^1.3 for mageplaza/module-smtp ./composer.json has been
> updated Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could
> not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> 
>   Problem 1
>     - The requested package mageplaza/module-core (locked at 1.3.13, required as                                                           
> ^1.4) is satisfiable by mageplaza/module-core[1.3.13] but these
> conflict with y                                                       
> our requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 2
>     - The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.1.12,                                                            
> required as 2.3.3) is satisfiable by
> magento/product-community-edition[2.1.12]                             
> but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.  
> Problem 3
>     - The requested package lusitanian/oauth (locked at v0.7.0, required as ~0.8                                                      
> .10) is satisfiable by lusitanian/oauth[v0.7.0] but these conflict
> with your req                                                         
> uirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 4
>     - The requested package pdepend/pdepend (locked at 2.4.0, required as 2.5.2)                                                            
> is satisfiable by pdepend/pdepend[2.4.0] but these conflict with your
> requireme                                                           
> nts or minimum-stability.   Problem 5
>     - The requested package phpunit/phpunit (locked at 4.1.0, required as ~6.5.0                                                            )
> is satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.1.0] but these conflict with your
> requirem                                                           
> ents or minimum-stability.   Problem 6
>     - The requested package sebastian/phpcpd (locked at 2.0.0, required as ~3.0.                                                     
> 0) is satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[2.0.0] but these conflict with
> your requir                                                           
> ements or minimum-stability.   Problem 7
>     - The requested package squizlabs/php_codesniffer (locked at 1.5.3, required                                                             as ~3.4.0) is satisfiable by squizlabs/php_codesniffer[1.5.3] but
> these conflic                                                         
> t with your requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 8
>     - magento/composer 1.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP versi                                                           
> on (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - magento/composer 1.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP versi                                                           
> on (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - magento/composer 1.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP versi                                                           
> on (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - magento/composer 1.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP versi                                                           
> on (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - magento/composer 1.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP versi                                                           
> on (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - Installation request for magento/composer (locked at 1.0.3) -> satisfiable                                                           
> by magento/composer[1.0.3].
```

### Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.12",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.1.9",
        "samgranger/module-store-code-body-class": "^2.0",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-japanese-language-pack": "dev-master",
        "mageplaza/module-core": "^1.4",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.3",
        "mageplaza/module-smtp": "^1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.14.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~3.0.0",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.4.5",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.4.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    } }
```

Comment: How did you update magento to new version? You can check Your current magento version in Admin page (top bottom right corner). Are you trying to update mageplaza on local env? How are You trying to do that?

Comment: @KonradSiamro I hired a developer(I don't know how he did it exactly) it says 2.3.3 in admin and from the URL check. Yes, I'm in local env ssh user, not root user.

Comment: How are You trying to do that? Maybe You should hire developer for that also?